# Batch script to switch between two proxies

Tags: batch-file, proxy

I'm using a batch script for my pc at work to switch between two proxy servers. Currently I have 2 separate scripts for each of the proxies which I use accordingly to which server I want to connect.

```
reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" ^
/v ProxyServer /t REG_SZ /d proxyAddress:port /f
```

Both scripts are the same, just the address is different. I would like to create a single batch file that changes between the two stored addresses (if one is in use, change it to the other one). Is there a way to return a value from REG_SZ entry and evaluate it to stored values?

Thanks

Comment: You are already using the [`reg` command](http://ss64.com/nt/reg.html), so have you ever considered to read its help (`reg /?`) and find whether it supports reading registry keys?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do like new lines and vars ;-) and have template for this.
You have to adapt Proxy1 and Proxy2 vars.

```
:: ToggleProxy.cmd
@Echo off
set "Key=HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings"
Set "Val=ProxyServer"
Set "Typ=REG_SZ"
Set "Proxy1=proxyAddress1:port1"
Set "Proxy2=proxyAddress2:port2"
for /f "tokens=3" %%R in (
  'Reg Query "%Key%" /v %Val% ^|find /i "%Val%"'
) do if "%%~R" equ "%Proxy1%" (
   Reg add "%Key%" /v %Val% /t %Typ% /d "%Proxy2%" /f
) else (
   Reg add "%Key%" /v %Val% /t %Typ% /d "%Proxy1%" /f
)
```

Comment: What is this? Cleancode? In batch? Where do you think we are here :P

Comment: I tried this solution, but it only switches the proxy if Proxy2 value is the current proxy settings (in this case it only does the else portion). It doesn't switch it back tho. Then I changed `do if "%%~R" equ "%Proxy1"` to `do if "%%~R" equ "192.168..."` and now the script works, like something was wrong with variable Proxy1. Strange cause it still changes the value stored in Proxy1 variable properly if Proxy2 was the current proxy, but it didn't evaluate the  same var properly in the if line. Thanks anyways, this solution works.

Answer (score 1):

Because new lines are boring anyways (I am sorry for the second line...):

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=3 delims= " %%a in ('reg query "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" /v ProxyServer /t REG_SZ ^| findstr "REG_SZ"') do set currentValue=%%a

if "%currentValue%"=="<proxySetting1>"(
REM set proxySetting2 here
) ELSE (
REM set proxySetting1 here
)
```

Using `regQuery` you can actually search for your key value. The loop is required to parse the output and read the value into the variable `currentValue`. You can then use this value to check whether proxy one is active or not and use your command above to change it accordingly.

Explanation of the loop:

The output of the query look like this for me:

```
KEY_ROOT_HERE\PATH\TO\KEY
Name    REG_TYPE    VALUE
```

So with `findstr REG_SZ` we only get the lower line of both. Then we have to take the third part of the string seperated by spaces (see the beginnning where it says `"tokens=3 delims= "` and the longest part is the query itself mostly taken from your question.

Comment: in the line: if "%currentValue%"=="<proxySetting1>"  if i enter proxy address like "<192.168...:8080> nothing happens, should i enter binary data here or?

Comment: I did not mean to include the `<>` it was to show that that is a variable part :) So it should be `if "%currentValue%"=="192.168....:8080"`

Comment: yeah, i'm quite new to the batch scripts, i played around with "" before your post, but even now after i change it to "%currentValue%"=="192.168....:8080", it still doesnt switch proxies (nothing happens) when i execute the script

Comment: You should remove the REM as well. It is equivalent to a comment. Forgot to mention

Comment: Thanks, i know REMs are comments, and i tried removing it, but it didn't help. I'm not quite sure why, but i managed to solve it and get it to work with @LotPings solution. Thank you both tho...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [user6811411 answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41737778/10840553) I created a more "generic" version.
I modified the script that you can inject the Proxy-Adresses from the command line. Makes it more versatile and you don't have to hardcode the adresses (maybe for security concerns or whatsoever).

Use it like that:
`<PATH>\switch_proxy.bat proxyVal1 proxyVal2`

```
@Echo off
set "Key=HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings"
Set "Val=ProxyServer"
Set "Typ=REG_SZ"
Set "Proxy1=%1"
Set "Proxy2=%2"
for /f "tokens=3" %%R in (
  'Reg Query "%Key%" /v %Val% ^|find /i "%Val%"'
) do if "%%~R" equ "%Proxy1%" (
   Reg add "%Key%" /v %Val% /t %Typ% /d "%Proxy2%" /f
) else (
   Reg add "%Key%" /v %Val% /t %Typ% /d "%Proxy1%" /f
)
```